# Create method argument with member function pointer from template types in C++ 11

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I want to achieve the following:

```
template <typename F>
class MyTemplate {
public:
    void SomeMethod(F f) {
        //...
    }

    template <typename C, typename O>
    void SomeMethod(C::*F f, O& o) {    // this does not work, I want a member function pointer here
        //...
    }
};

static void StaticFunction(int);

class SomeClass {
public:
    void MemberMethod(int);
};


MyTemplate<void(int)> mt;
mt.SomeMethod(StaticFunction);
SomeClass SomeClassInstance;
mt.SomeMethod(&SomeClass::MemberMethod, SomeClassInstance); // I want to call it like this
```

I want to create a template with a function type parameter. The template should 'create' overloads for C-style or static function pointers as well as members functions.
How can I create the member function type from the free function type that should be used to declare the template instance?

I want to be able to use the template with types like:

- void(void)
- void(int)
- int(void)
- int(int)
- int(int, int, int, int)
- void(int, int, int, int)
- etc.

Comment: I think you mean `template <typename C, typename O> void SomeMethod(F C::* f, O& o);` Note the placement of `F`. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7160e4a38987679)

Comment: You should at least make an effort to write code that is correct except for the one thing you don't know how to do. This is sloppy. No `class` before the declaration of `SomeClass`, no semicolons after class definitions... and there's no declaration of `MyClass` (I guess you meant `SomeClass`)

Comment: @dyp You should make that an answer.

Comment: @dyp: That syntax is new to me. Does it have a name?

Comment: @Nemo `F C::* f`? "Pointer to member function of class C returning F". F is void, C is MyClass.

Comment: @PeterSchneider It's "pointer to member of class C of type F".

Comment: @T.C. Ah, f doesn't have to be a function -- was indeed not aware of that. Although, with F being void, I'm wondering whether it can be something else in this instantiation ;-)

Comment: @PeterSchneider: Actually in this example F is `void(int)`; i.e. a function taking `int` and returning `void`. Apparently this syntax is new to you, too :-)

Comment: @Nemo Hm. Not daily encountered for sure.

Comment: @dyp: thanks, that is what I was looking for. Works perfectly. Funny syntax. I have never seen it before.

Comment: @Brian: sorry, you are right. I should have reviewed my own typing before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer provided by dyp:

```
template <typename F>
class MyTemplate {
public:
    void SomeMethod(F f) {
        //...
    }

    template <typename C, typename O>
    void SomeMethod(F C::* f, O& o) {    // this does work
        //...
    }
};

static void StaticFunction(int) {}

struct SomeClass {
public:
    void MemberMethod(int) {}
};

int main()
{
    MyTemplate<void(int)> mt;
    mt.SomeMethod(StaticFunction);
    SomeClass SomeClassInstance;
    mt.SomeMethod(&SomeClass::MemberMethod, SomeClassInstance); // I want to call it like this
}
```